# bloom says "Cannot push to remote release repository"

Tags: ros, bloom-release, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got this error when I ran `bloom-release` with a metapackage that I joined maintainer team after it's been already released. Am I missing anything?

```
----error msg----
$ bloom-release pkg_a groovy
==> Fetching 'pkg_a' repository from
'https://github.com/ros-gbp/pkg_a-release.git'
==> Testing for push permission on release repository
Username for 'https://github.com': my_github_account
Password for 'https://my_github_account@github.com':
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing
https://github.com/ros-gbp/pkg_a-release.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
Cannot push to remote release repository.
```

I suspect I don't have a push privilege to the release repository (but [tutorials of bloom](http://www.ros.org/wiki/bloom/Tutorials) didn't tell me to ask for a push access).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57485/bloom-says-%22cannot-push-to-remote-release-repository%22/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must have push access to the release repository in order to release into it.

I thought that went with out saying, but also bloom informs you of it if you lack the required privileges, so I did not put that in the tutorials. Feel free to update them and clarify that if you wish.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-03-07**:
After wondering which is a good wiki page to add a note, I added 1 line http://www.ros.org/wiki/bloom/Tutorials/ReleaseCatkinPackage.